# change the color of the tableView?.tableFooterView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

[image]

I created a tableView like the picture. There is space between section and cell. So the color of the space is the tableview default color.

To remove the extra lines on the tableview, I added a UIVIew() to `tableView?.tableFooterView`.

```
let footerView = UIView()
self.tableView?.tableFooterView = footerView
```

I want to let the UIView's color same in the "target color" ont the picture.

I have tried like below, but it doesn't work.

```
let footerView = UIView()
footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
footerView.tintColor = UIColor.black
self.tableView?.tableFooterView = footerView
```

What should I do ?
Thanks!

Comment: Since you didn't set the height of the footer view, and that is not the way to go, set your desired color on the table s backgroundview as already mentionned by nirva D

Answer (score 4):

Try to Set the `tableView`'s `backgroundColor` for that.

```
self.tableView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //Or color that you want
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an another solution if you want to use different color for the tableview footer.

**Swift 4**

```
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    let screenRect = view.bounds;
    let screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    let screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    let footerHeight = screenHeight - ((YOUR_SECTION_HEIGHT * SECTION_COUNT) + (YOUR_ROW_HEIGHT * ROW_COUNT))
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight - footerHeight))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray // or your custom color
    tableView.tableFooterView?.addSubview(footerView)
```

**Objective-C**

```
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    CGRect screenRect = self.view.bounds;
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    CGFloat footerHeight = screenHeight - ((YOUR_SECTION_HEIGHT * SECTION_COUNT) + (YOUR_ROW_HEIGHT * ROW_COUNT));
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenWidth, screenHeight - footerHeight)];
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor]; // or your custom color
    [self.tableView.tableFooterView addSubview:footerView];
```